# Understandig solution of ODE through eigefunctions expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume I have a differential equation of the type
$$F''(x)+V(x)F(x)=S(x)$$
I want to solve it with the expansion in eigenfunction method. Assuming that I know the eigenfunctions $E_n(x)$, the source term can be expanded as $S(x)=\sum_n c_n E_n(x)$, so the DE becomes:
$$F''(x)+V(x)F(x)=\sum_n c_n E_n(x)$$

How do I proceed now?

Comment: Do you know $V$ and $S$?

Comment: @Eli I wanted to keep the discussion general, but if it is needed I can add their definition

Comment: if you can represent $V(x)$ as $-(f^2(x)+f'(x))$ the solution for the homogeneous equation is known! 

http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0243.pdf

And if $V(x)$ takes certain forms the solution is finite.